# How to convert e-06 in php

Tags: php

I want to convert e-06 to number in PHP
my code is :

```
<?php
$hashrate = 5000000000;
$str = file_get_contents('http://alloscomp.com/bitcoin/calculator/json?hashrate='.$hashrate.'');
$data = json_decode($str, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array
$coinperhour = $data['coins_per_hour'];
echo $coinperhour;
?>
```

after i run the code, it show 2.2015778741378E-6. how to convert it to number?
i have try use `echo (int)$coinperhour;` but the code show 0, how to fix it? i want to the code is show 0.00000220157 . thank you

Comment: it is a number already

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152864/how-to-convert-a-number-in-php-for-example-1-905e06-will-be-1905000

Comment: @MikeDaVinci i already tested the code, but the code show 0

Comment: `(int)$coinperhour;` do you even understand that `2*10^-6 ` is less then 1 so will (naturally) yield 0 when converted to integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i = 2.2015778741378E-6;
echo $i;                    // 2.2015778741378E-6
echo number_format ($i,11); // 0.00000220158
```

Comment: @Alexandro Setiawan Glad to help